# Python cron job with docker-compose and airflow

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm trying to run this Pyhon function with Docker and Airflow, it should be a simple cron job but I can't make it work. I am very unexperienced with both of them.

Below is my Python code and right below it is the error raised in Airflow which is running inside a Docker container.

Docker version: 20.10.12
Python 3.9

```
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
seven_days_ago = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(7),
                                           datetime.datetime.min.time())

def f_run():
    print('blabla')
    return f_run

runner = f_run()

default_args = {
    'owner': 'teste',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}


args = {
    'owner': 'renan',
    'start_date': seven_days_ago  # make start date in the past
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='teste',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='@daily'  # make this workflow happen every day
)

with dag:
    func = PythonOperator(
        task_id='run',
python_callable = runner
    )
```

And in airflow the error raised is:

```
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: You need to pass a reference to `python_callable`. But `runner` has the result of a function (notice the `()` after the function name.  function is already called and returned the result back to `runner`).  you don't have to wrap with another variable `runner`, you can directly pass `python_callable=f_run`

Comment: Ah, you are returning the reference to the self within the `f_run`.  I am not sure but this _could_ theoretically work but do you actually mean to do so?

Comment: No, actually everything that I want is the function to run when the cron job starts. Some suggestion about how to do it?
Obs: You can change the code as you want to make it work with this function, as I dont have much experience with docker/airflow.

Comment: Ok, I see. In that case, change the return value of `f_run` to something else.  Do not return the self reference. Then try `python_callable=f_run`.

Comment: I did something similar, and it worked, It didnt return a thing in python now, and previously this is there that it was breaking, and now function is just being called inside airflow method. Thank you!! `def f_run(): print('blabla') with dag: func = PythonOperator( task_id='run', python_callable=f_run)`